# Convert.ToDateTime in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to generate a LINQ statement like this type of SQL statement

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement
WHERE  FileName LIKE '%latest%'
       AND ToDate = (SELECT min(ToDate)
                     FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement
                     WHERE  CAST (getdate() AS DATE) <= CAST (Todate AS DATE)
                            AND FromDate = (SELECT max(FromDate)
                                            FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement
                                            WHERE  CAST (getdate() AS DATE) >= CAST (FromDate AS DATE)));
```

I have generated Linq statement as followes:

```
objAdvList = objAdvList
            .Where(x => x.ToDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList
                .Where(y => y.FromDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate)))
                .Select(y => y.FromDate)
                ))
                .Select(x => x)
                .ToList();
```

Where objAdvList is a List type collection of

```
class AdvertisementAccess
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

But this code give me an error message as followes:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectListIterator`2[AdvertisementAccess,System.DateTime]' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'.

Is there anyone to solve my problem?

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: Is this Entity Framework, NHibernate, LINQ to SQL, etc?

Comment: If you want an exact replica of the data that would be returned from your SQL, then you should look at the EntityFunctions class, particularly the TruncateTime function which will do the equivalent to your casting to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for your quick and useful replies.
By using your help I have generated my Linq statement which is able to fulfill my requirement as replacement of sql statement given below:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement
WHERE  ToDate = (SELECT min(ToDate)
                     FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement
                     WHERE  FromDate = (SELECT max(FromDate)
                                            FROM   dbo.tbl_Advertisement))
```

My Linq statement is as followes:

```
objAdvList = objAdvList
            .Where(x => x.ToDate.Date == objAdvList
                .Where(y => y.FromDate.Date == objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate.Date))
                .Select(y => y.ToDate.Date).Min()
                )
                .Select(x => x)
                .ToList();
```

Thanks again,
Mayank

Answer (score 4):

Your inner query results in a set of results. However, `Convert.ToDateTime` is looking for a single value. You can use either `Single`, `First`, or `Last` to choose a value from this set of values generated by the inner query.

To use `Single` to retrieve the **only** result of the inner LINQ query, try the following code:

```
objAdvList = objAdvList
    .Where(x => x.ToDate == objAdvList
        .Where(y => y.FromDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate)))
        .Select(y => y.FromDate).Single()
    )
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you need to pick the first result from a list of possibilities, use `First` instead:

```
objAdvList = objAdvList
    .Where(x => x.ToDate == objAdvList
        .Where(y => y.FromDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate)))
        .Select(y => y.FromDate).First()
    )
    .ToList();
```

In either case, I removed the `.Select(x => x)` expression, which doesn't do anything. This expression will merely select all values `x` and return them untransformed.

I also removed the call to `Convert.ToDateTime`, as you're already comparing two dates. You do not need to convert a date value to a date.

Comment: You may want to convert a datetime field to a date for comparison however, for example, `7/8/2013 3:00:00 >= 7/8/2013 4:00:00` is false, however, `CAST('7/8/2013 3:00:00' as DATE) >= CAST('7/8/2013 4:00:00' as DATE)` is true.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of your first `Convert.ToDateTime()` call is an enumeration; make sure you suffix it with a `.FirstOrDefault()` or `Single()`:

```
objAdvList = objAdvList
            .Where(x => x.ToDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList
                .Where(y => y.FromDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate)))
                .Select(y => y.FromDate)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                ))
                .Select(x => x)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: And there's actually no need to call Convert.ToDateTime() on an object which is already a DateTime.

Comment: Yup. And as David says, there's also no need for the `Select(x => x)`.

Comment: There is actually a need to convert something that is a datetime to a date, if you want to only compare the date portions instead of the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query instead of your query.

```
(objAdvList
            .Where(x => x.ToDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList
                .Where(y => y.FromDate == Convert.ToDateTime(objAdvList.Max(z => z.FromDate)))
                .Select(y => y.FromDate)
                ))
                .Select(x => x)).Single();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query looks a bit odd, but this is what it looks like converted to LINQ over Entities, I think:

```
var objAdvList=objAdvList
     .Where(a=>a.Filename.Contains("latest"))
     .Where(a=>a.ToDate==objAdvList
         .Where(a2=>EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)<=EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a2.FromDate))
         .Where(a2=>EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a2.FromDate)<=objAdvList
             .Where(a3=>EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)>=EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a3.FromDate))
             .Max(a3=>a3.FromDate))
         .Min(a2=>a2.ToDate))
```